# Javascript Make Sure Inputs all Have Unique Values

Tags: javascript, loops, input

Ok, I know I'm overthinking this, because it just isn't coming to me at all. I have a group of inputs. How would I go about checking to make sure that their values are all unique? Thanks!

Comment: Can you use jquery or only pure javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inputs=[], flag=false;
$('input').each(function(){
    if ($.inArray(this.value, inputs) != -1) flag=true ;
    inputs.push(this.value);
});

if (flag==true) {
   //duplicates exists
}
```

Comment: Wow, so many responses so quickly :p I tried a couple of them until I hit this one and it's simplicity was dead on. PERFECT! Thanks a million adeneo :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a validation issue. You can do in the odd way (with a heavy bunch of if clauses, which I guess is not desired), trying to add all those inputs in an array and check them inside a while loop. Or perhaps, if those inputs are strings, you can concat them and try something with regexps.

There should be more answers for this, and sure better that the one summoned here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pseudo-set implementation and check that each entry isn't already repeated
That is, iterate and check, if `x in set` return false

http://www.javascriptexamples.org/2011/01/17/how-to-implement-a-set-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PF4rD/

```
function uniqueValues(elements) {

    var values = {},
        len = elements.length,
        i = 0;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (!values[elements[i].value]) values[elements[i].value] = true;
        else return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
var areUnique = true;
$.each($("Input_Selector",function(){
var val = $(this).val();
  $.each($("Input_Selector",function(){
   if(val == $(this).val()){areUnique = false;}
  });
}));
//check the value of areUnique here
```

Comment: You could possibly improve efficiency by checking the value of areUnique inside the first loop, breaking if it's false.